# FreeMarker nested data : error while parsing

Tags: templates, freemarker

While processing the below code:

```
template.process(data, filewriter);
```

template is an object of freemarker.template.Template class. created by

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(new Version("2.3.23"));
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
try {
    cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(
            "dir/to/templates"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

this.template = cfg.getTemplate(path);
```

filewriter is the FileWriter object

data is a map, which is populated as

```
key ->"page.title", value ->"Dummy Page title"
key ->"page.body", value ->"Dummy Page Body"
```

I have used the following template

```
<html>
<head>
<title>${page.title}</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This page is generated using freemarker
</p>
<p>
${page.body}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

While processing, I am getting following error:

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> page  [in template "default.ftl" at line 3, column 10]

----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${page.title}  [in template "default.ftl" at line 3, column 8]
----
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

PS: This whole setup works fine, if I change the name "page.title" to "pagetitle" and "page.body" to "pagebody" at both the places.
I really want to use '.' to namespace my values.

Comment: @jonbullock Please help

Comment: Just an unrelated side note: `new Version("2.3.23")` can be written as `Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23`. (See my answer otherwise.)

Comment: I actually want it config driven, so I have moved the string version to properties file.
I guess that won't be possible if I use Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23

Answer (score 1):

As the exception:

```
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${page.title}  [in template "default.ftl" at line 3, column 8]
```

freemarker will parse `${page.title}` as nested object, you can try to use [dataModel](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html)

```
${.dataModel["page.title"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a public Java class (say, `com.example.Page`) that has `public String getTitle()` and `public String getBody()` methods and put the object into `data` with name `page`, or create a `Map<String, Object>` that contains `Map` entries with `"title"` and `"body"` keys and put that into the `data` with name `page`. Then `page.title` and such will work. Or if you really need to use dot as part of the name, you have to escape the dot so that it knows that you don't mean getting a sub-variable: `page\.title`.

Answer (score 0):

I create a class named "UrlEntity" which has private member named url with set and get method,then I create a urlEntity named path.I use it by `var redir = '${path.getUrl()}';` and I restart my project,then problem solved.